# How do I add a constant integer to a nested list?

Tags: python, list

I have tried the following code:

```py
list = [[j+i+10 for j in range(1,9)] for i in range (9)]
print (list)
```

which gives me the output:

```py
[[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]
```

However I am looking for an output:

```
list = [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],...[91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]]
```

Am i able to do this without the use of any python packages?

Comment: This is totally beside the point, but `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). In a small example like this, it's not a big problem, just a bit unclear, but in more involved code, it's better to use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `lst` or `L`. For an example, see [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "typo" since the problem was a basic mistake in arithmetic and the code was actually correct otherwise.

Comment: sorry guys im new to programming, thank you all for the correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" is in used arithmetic function `j+i+10`. To get desired result, use multiplication instead of addition: `j+i*10` (also, the last range should go from `1` instead of `0`).

Try:

```py
lst = [[j + i * 10 for j in range(1, 9)] for i in range(1, 10)]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
    [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38],
    [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
    [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58],
    [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68],
    [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78],
    [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88],
    [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98],
]
```